# Disable Auto-complete(autocomplete="off") using STRUTS

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, struts-1, custom-tags

i tried to disable auto complete(autocomplete="off") in struts framework,the process i followed is 
1)In Strut-html.tld file i had few attributes of TextTag so added autocomplete attribute

```
<tagclass>org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TextTag</tagclass>
<attribute>
<name>autocomplete</name>
<required>false</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>   
</attribute>
```

2)i wrote a class for customtag  by extending org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TextTag

```
import org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TextTag.*;

public class TextTag extends org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TextTag { 


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String autocomplete = null;

public String getAutocomplete()
{ return autocomplete; }

public void setAutoComplete(String autocomplete)
{
this.autocomplete = autocomplete; 

} 

protected void prepareOtherAttributes(StringBuffer sb) { 


if (autocomplete != null) { 

sb.append(" autocomplete=\""+autocomplete+"\""); 
}
}
}
```

3) And in jsp page i added autocomplete="off" attribute

so when i run my application im getting the following error

```
/index.jsp(1): Error in using tag library uri='/tags/struts-html' prefix='html':
The Tagclass'org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag' has no setter method corresponding  
to TLD declared attribute 'name', (JSP 1.1 spec, 5.4.1)  probably occurred due to an 
error in /index.jsp line 1:  
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html" %>
```

Some one please help me to solve this error and i tried with javascript as well but its not working.

```
function DisableAutocomplete()
{
var AC_Disable_login=document.forms[0].elements['loginID'];
AC_Disable_login.setAttribute ("autocomplete", "off");
}
```

Comment: Format the code properly.

Comment: Hi Braj, i think the code is properly formatted now.

Comment: Still some alignment issues are there but no problem it looks better than previous.

Comment: It might help you. Read [form/input tags and turning off autocomplete](http://www.coderanch.com/t/54020/Struts/form-input-tags-turning-autocomplete)

Comment: Thanks for the link,Even i tried in the same way but it is showing the same error.

Comment: Post your `index.jsp` page here.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to rewrite Struts 1.x to add this functionality. All you need is to add the following lines:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(":text").attr("autocomplete", "off");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi paul, thanks for your answer, were should I add(link)this above mentioned part of code?

Comment: You can add it in the `<head>` section or in the `<body>` at the end, where do you want.

Comment: Hi paul,thanks for your help,As i mentioned above my attribute in struts application is text so can i apply your code snippet for text attribue instead of input attribute...like     $(":text").attr("autocomplete", "off");

Comment: HI paul i have used <html:text property="loginID" style="width:133px;" maxlength="32"/> in jsp so to auto complete this text box can i use $(":text").attr("autocomplete", "off")?

Comment: Yes! That's a best way. I updated my answer in order to include this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick and dirty hack documented here http://www.coderanch.com/t/54020/Struts/form-input-tags-turning-autocomplete that embeds the autocomplete option inside another form element.

For example

```
<html:form method="post\" autocomplete=\"off" action="verify_login.do" >
```

Struts renders as

```
<form name="LoginForm" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="verify_login.do">
```

Its not pretty but it saves the need to redefine Struts taglibs.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many solutions 
1. including the dirty hack given above, 
2. setting autocomplete off for form by calling a script at page load:

```js
    <body class="article-page auxillary-page" onload="autocompletion()">
 function autocompletion()
 {
         for (i=0; i<document.forms.length; i++) {
         document.forms[i].setAttribute("AutoComplete","off");
        }
 }
```

and few others, None of them seems to work.. 
I think the only solution is:
change your tag to html tag, and then in submit function for form assign that value to your required bean property.

you can use

```html
<input type="password" name="password1" maxlength="4" size="25" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" autocomplete="off" />
```

This worked for me on struts 1 , J7 Eclipse keplar, wildfly server.